# Как создать большую матрицу из true random чисел?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, numpy

Мне нужно создать матрицу N*N из true random чисел,
где N может быть от десяти тысяч до миллиона

Я нашла библиотеку quantumrandom, которая возвращает рандомные числа из квантового компьютера. Вот только в коде, который возвращает матрицу остатков деления чисел на 2

```
matrix = [] #array with ALL random numbers
div = np.zeros(N) + 2 

for i in range (0,N):
    row = qr.get_data(array_length=N) # array of N random numbers
    row = row % div
    matrix.append (row) #matrix N*N
```

даже при N=1000 выбивает  ошибку exception timeout.

Мой вопрос о том, какие другие средства я могу использовать на Python, которые смогут возвратить матрицу случайных чисел большого размера?

Модуль random мне не подходит

Comment: А в чём смысл использовать именно "true random" данные? Почему нельзя использовать стандартный модуль random?

Comment: `array_length cannot be larger than 1024`

Comment: потому что это нужно для математической задачи и если буду использовать модуль random, то решение будет некорректным.

Comment: А ваша мат.задача будет корректна, если тру рандом вернет 42 нуля подряд, что ТеорВер не запрещает? Или вам все же надо равномерное распределение

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **seed()**

```
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(20)
N = int(input()
arr = np.array([random.random() for i in range(N)])
for i in range(N-1):
  arr = np.vstack((arr, np.array([random.random() for i in range(N)])))

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант создать np.array:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.random.randint(maxVal, size=(rows, columns))  // от 0 до maxVal, rowsХcolumns
```

Если нужно преобразовать в list:

```
matrix.tolist()
```